# Problem with animating 6 objects combined into 1

Tags: animation

I have 6 bullets and a revolver, the bullets I used <kbd>CTRL+J</kbd> to join them. I then animated a reloading scene. Then I wanted one of the bullets to shoot, not all 6 of them. So on frame 130, I took the 6 bullets and selected one of them and hit <kbd>P+Selection</kbd> so only that bullet is selectable. Then I animated it to shoot out of the gun, and then after animating it i played the animation and it shows all 6 bullets shooting out of the barrel, even though on frame 1 they are separate objects (I do not know why) and then beyond frame 130 the whole barrel shoots out..
Here is a video giving an example of my problem:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP46Z.jpg

Why is it doing this and how can i fix it? Is their perhaps an addon that can fix this?

Comment: I dont believe you can animate joining and un joining objects, How about you join 5 of them and the loose bullet you parent to the 5 that are joined. Then you can just animate the single bullett

Comment: i have 6 bullets i want to shoot

Comment: @Optimus please make use the tools on this site to upload images so that they become visible as part of your post. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dcm8C.png

Answer (score 1):

You should have to do it with separated bullets (objects).

This is my solution for your particular flow:

Create a **shape key** and you can animate that shape key.

See the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whats causing your error, But a solution to your problem could be to make a separate mesh with only 5 bullets and a separate bullet (That would be animated coming out of the barrel) and make the 6 bullets hide and the 5 and 1 show at the frame you need to shoot.